# Convert number to date format within an array

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, array, date

I have a custom field of `deal_date` that I need to work into an array. When using directly on a template I can just set the output format directly in the ACF UI. However I obviously cant use get_field within an array, so the output in this scenario is just the number showing up as a string (ex. 20180422) - how can I convert this within the array so that it shows up as a date (ex April 22, 2018).

```
$posts = get_posts( $args );

        if( $posts ) :
            foreach( $posts as $k => $post ) {
                $source[$k]['ID'] = $post->ID;                                      
                $source[$k]['label'] = array ( $post->post_title, $post->deal_date);                
                $source[$k]['permalink'] = get_permalink( $post->ID );
```

Comment: `get_field('deal_date, $post->ID)` would do it? See the [doc](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes that is what I thought would have worked but it does not because `get_field()` is not a defined method.

Comment: ugh, ignore me, you are correct! That worked, there was a small error in my code. THANK YOU!

Comment: I guess you tried with `$post->get_field()` ? :p Anyway, I'm glad it worked. :)

Comment: lol yep, exactly what I did ha. ty again!